# Workspace preparation and cleanup for DNA work

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques

What steps should be taken in a molecular lab environment to help ensure that DNA samples/stocks are not contaminated, or contaminate other objects in the lab?

Comment: VTC because this question is identical to the later one, and the later one is better asked and has better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment section:

Mostly segregation of PCR-amplified DNA from non-amplified DNA. Typically no DNA or sample should ever enter a specific room designed to prepare the MasterMix for PCR (this is true for diagnostic labs, in the research one I never saw that). For the rest, following good laboratory practices (google that) should be enough.